# Know how disconnected the websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, java-websocket

I'm doing an implementation of websockets. I have the connection part working, but when disconnecting I do not know how to identify how is it... to delete it from active connections.
Here is my code till now:

```
const clients = [];

wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
const user = url.parse(req.url, true).query.user;   // user comes via query string
const screen = url.parse(req.url, true).query.screen;   // current action 

const connectionItem = {
    user: user, 
    screen: screen, 
    connection: ws
    };

 clients.push(connectionItem);
 
 ws.on('close', function(){
        // how to know who is it to delete from clients array ?
  });
  
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `connectionItem` is in scope, so you can just remove it from your list of clients: `clients.splice(clients.findIndex( item => item === connectionItem), 1)`

Comment: Great! Thanks  !